# Checking value of YES/NO datatype in Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

In one of of table, I have field that stores the value in YES/NO data type.

I am trying to check the value of the field using the following query but receiving error as shown in the picture below.

```
public string getAccess(string username)
        {
            // Create connection object
            OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            oleConn.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT [admin] FROM [Users] WHERE [username]='" + username + "'";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);
            string x = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();


            oleConn.Close();


            return x;
        }
```

The field **admin** is in YES/NO type data field.

[image]

How can i check the value of the data type?
Please correct by query if wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The yes/no field in Access is equivalent to the bit field type in SQL Server, so I believe you should be returning a Boolean from your method instead of a string, try something like this:

```
public bool isAdmin(string username)
{
    // Create connection object
    OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    oleConn.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT [admin] FROM [Users] WHERE [username]='" + username + "'";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);
    bool x = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    oleConn.Close();

    return x;
}
```

Or if you are determined to have string be the return value, then this:

```
public string getAccess(string username)
{
    // Create connection object
    OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    oleConn.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT [admin] FROM [Users] WHERE [username]='" + username + "'";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);
    bool x = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    oleConn.Close();

    return x ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed method type to bool and it works

```
public bool getAccess(string username)
        {
            // Create connection object
            OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            oleConn.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT [admin] FROM [Users] WHERE [username]='" + username + "'";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);
            bool x = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();


            oleConn.Close();


            return x;
        }
```